# Adding filter to Wordpress dashboard (not posts)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, filter, dashboard

I'm looking to filter a list in the dashboard of our company's project management site. I want to filter it by users but currently [it can only sort by date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GC1w.jpg). The users are displayed on hover so all of the information is there in the table, I just want to add a search bar to filter names. Is this relatively easily done? I am mostly front end so my php skills are somewhat lacking. The plugin being used is [Panorma projects](https://www.projectpanorama.com/).

Everything plugin I've tried so far is for filtering posts and they don't carry over to the panorama page.

Comment: Yes it can be done: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-make-your-custom-column-sortable--wp-25095; http://wpdreamer.com/2014/04/how-to-make-your-wordpress-admin-columns-sortable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ic the code for adding custom filters in WP custom Post types.

Just change the code to you requirements.

In first function in the select box get all the users or particular users by role.

And in the second function macth the selected records with Author ID

```
 function wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts(){
        $type = 'post';
        if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
            $type = $_GET['post_type'];
        }

        //only add filter to post type you want
        if ('POST_TYPE' == $type){
            //change this to the list of values you want to show
            //in 'label' => 'value' format
            $values = array(
                'label' => 'value', 
                'label1' => 'value1',
                'label2' => 'value2',
            );
            ?>
            <select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE">
            <option value=""><?php _e('Filter By ', 'wose45436'); ?></option>
            <?php
                $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
                foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
                    printf
                        (
                            '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                            $value,
                            $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
                            $label
                        );
                    }
            ?>
            </select>
            <?php
        }
    }


    add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse45436_posts_filter' );
    /**
     * if submitted filter by post meta
     * 
     * make sure to change META_KEY to the actual meta key
     * and POST_TYPE to the name of your custom post type
     * @author Ohad Raz
     * @param  (wp_query object) $query
     * 
     * @return Void
     */
    function wpse45436_posts_filter( $query ){
        global $pagenow;
        $type = 'post';
        if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
            $type = $_GET['post_type'];
        }
        if ( 'POST_TYPE' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '') {
            $query->query_vars['author'] = ID of the user from $_GET;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped. What if the value in the users column is an array of users?

Comment: You can fetch all the users through loop in wp.. inside the loop pass all the user IDs and user names in array .. then a next foreach loop (from the array created above) outside the above WP loop creating options of the select box and pass user IDs and name in the options..

Comment: Would you be able to show me what the $query->query_vars['author'] = ID of the user from $_GET; line would look like as a loop?

Comment: $query->query_vars['author'] = $_GET['selected_user']; name of the select box created above should be selected_user

Comment: you only have to set the author parameter not the entire loop.. it will modify the loop adding the author parameter..

Comment: I think I understand now. I'm looking for user not author though and https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars is telling me that I can't query user